How do I protect access to my server on a certain port?
I have a Ubuntu v22.04 server where I am running three applications, each on a different port. Let's assume its IP address is 1.2.3.4.
One application is running on 1.2.3.4:3000, the second one on 1.2.3.4:4000, and finally the third one on 1.2.3.4:5000.
I would like to protect the applications running on 1.2.3.4:4000 and 1.2.3.4:5000 with HTTP Authentication, so when someone puts to the URL 1.2.3.4:4000 or 1.2.3.4:5000, then HTTP Authentication will pop up and the visitor will need to enter credentials to use the app on that particular IP:PORT.
What's the best way to do it? I would also want to mention that when I deploy code to these two applications (1.2.3.4:4000, 1.2.3.4:4000), I want to be able to do so without entering the credentials.
Thank you in advance.

If the applications themselves can't do HTTP Basic auth, then put them on some other port (maybe localhost only), and use nginx or apache2 to do the auth and proxy to it

@muru thank you for your reply. Why should it be on some other port and not on the ports the apps are running on? I am using nginx on the Ubuntu server.

Because then they'd continue to be accessible directly?
